# #include issue in C++

Tags: c++, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

I have 3 classes.
The main class is `Form1`
The other two are `Form2` & `Class3`
I included Form2 & Class3 in Form1, I mean I have in Form1 the following:

```
#include "Form2.h"
#include "Class3.h"
```

Also, in Form2 I included Class3, so I have in Form2 the following:

```
#include "Class3.h"
```

But I get redefine error, how I can solve this.

I always face like this issue, some time it is enough to include headers in `stdafx.h` but sometime doesn't work. So the other question how I can utilize and make use of  `stdafx.h` which is created by default in my C++/CLI winform project?

Comment: I suggest having one single header file `*.hh` for your entire project (unless it is very big).

Comment: I think that is truly, truly awful advice, Basile. It is far better practice to have a header file for each every .cpp file. Far, far better.

Comment: @Aan: what is your error? What does your code look like. It sounds like you need to start using [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) in your .h files, but I can't be sure based on the information you've provided.

Comment: You've got a file named `Class3.h`, but there's no class defined there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding this in Class3.h:

```
#ifndef _CLASS3_H
#define _CLASS3_H

/* your code here */

#endif
```

That should work

So you understand what is going on, what this is doing is preventing your Class3.h to redefine everything if it has already been done. In your program, Form1 uses Class3, but so does Form2. The first time Form2 is included, so is Class3, then, the next line you try to include Class3 again and then you get a redefinition error.

Hope that makes it clear for you

p.s.: I strongly recommend that you do this with all your .h files, though

Answer (score 3):

Use [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) or [`#pragma once`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once).